# Tkinter: Can't seem to set default value for checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set the default value as checked in the following code:

```
class Options(object):   # To clear out the previous widgets
  def __init__(self, mains):
     for widget in mains.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

class Settings(Options):   # Options destroys the previous widgets.
  def __init__(self, mains):        # mains is the main loop of the program
    super().__init__(mains)

    self.fast_var = tk.IntVar()
    self.fast_check = tk.Checkbutton(mains, text='Fast', variable=self.fast_var,
                                           width=5, height=1)
    self.fast_check.config(font=('Ariel', 13), fg='Black', bg='White')
    self.fast_check.select()
    self.fast_check.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.2)

    self.heavy_var = tk.IntVar()
    self.heavy_check = tk.Checkbutton(mains, text='Heavy',variable=self.heavy_var,
                                      width=5, height=1)
    self.heavy_check.config(font=('Ariel', 13), fg='Black', bg='White')
    self.heavy_check.select()
    self.heavy_check.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
```

But, no matter what I do, it just doesn't seem to work.
When I print the values of fast_var and heavy_var it displays 1, but still the checkbuttons are not checked.
I have tried using the following code instead, but that didn't work either:

```
class Settings(Options):
  def __init__(self, mains):
    super().__init__(mains)

    self.fast_var = tk.IntVar()
    self.fast_var.set(1)
    self.fast_check = tk.Checkbutton(mains, text='Fast', variable=self.fast_var,
                                     width=5, height=1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    self.fast_check.config(font=('Ariel', 13), fg='Black', bg='White')
    self.fast_check.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.2)

    self.heavy_var = tk.IntVar()
    self.heavy_var.set(1)
    self.heavy_check = tk.Checkbutton(mains, text='Heavy', variable=self.heavy_var, 
                                      width=5, height=1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    self.heavy_check.config(font=('Ariel', 13), fg='Black', bg='White')
    self.heavy_check.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
```

Comment: It is being selected/unselected, the problem is with the colors, try adding `selectcolor='Black'` to the `config` call to make the tick appear as white on black background.

Comment: Can you provide a _complete_ example? When I add in the missing pieces, your code works fine for me. When I run the above, the checkbuttons are automatically selected. My guess is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. Is that true?

Comment: That doesn't work, I commented out the .config and it still didn't work. I noticed I had previously put fg= as bg= and vice-versa in the code sample, I have since corrected that. @GáborFekete

Comment: The complete version has an extra label with text='Choose Method' beside the checkbuttons. And no, I have only called Tk() once. Since your code works fine, can you state the OS and python version? @BryanOakley

Comment: It works me me on OSX with python 3.8.4. It also works with python 2.7 when I adjust the call to `super`. However, I'm guessing what `Options` is, and I'm guessing at how and when you're creating the instance of `Settings` and `tk.Tk()`, and I also had to fix the broken indentation.

Comment: Does manually selecting by clicking work? That would at least mean, there is no problem with the colors. The problem could be in the `Options` class then.

Comment: I am using the latest Windows 10 with Python 3.8.5. I have adjusted the question to include the Options class. And the settings class is called by a button from the previous menu using `command=lambda: Settings(root)` @BryanOakley

Comment: Yeah. The colour doesn't seem to be the issue. It doesn't change at all if I comment out `self.fast_check.config(font=('Ariel', 13), fg='Black', bg='White')` . I have updated the question to include the Options class if you want to take a look. @Wups

Comment: This is a good illustration of why a proper [mcve] is so important. The way you're creating `Settings` is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how you are instantiating the `Settings` class, the entire object is getting garbage-collected. The widgets still exist, but the underlying variables do not. When the variables are garbage-collected, the checkbuttons get reset to zero.

You should be able to verify this by making sure the instance isn't being destroyed by the garbage collector. For example, you could assign the instance to a global variable:

```
def show_settings():
    global settings
    settings = Settings(root)

...
button = tk.Button(root, text="foo", command=show_settings)
```

Comment: Thanks for the splendid explanation, man! Your solution seemed to have fixed the issue.